# What is the criteria for compiler decides between compile time and run time function binding in java

Tags: java

First of all, I feel it is very weird that Java sometimes uses run-time binding and sometimes compile time binding. Had it not been much simpler if it were always runtime binding? Anyways. My question is as follows:

In the following code:

```
public class Animal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Generic Animal Eating Generically");
    }
}

public class Horse extends Animal {
    @override
    public void eat() {//overridden eat method
        System.out.println("Horse eating hay ");
    }
    public void eat(String s) {//overloaded eat method
        System.out.println("Horse eating " + s);
    }
}
```

Question:
1.In the code below, I know that "which eat method to run?" is decided at compile time. Too obvious. But what is the criteria to decide it?

```
Animal a = new Animal();
a.eat();
```

2.What about in following code.

```
Animal a = new Horse();//line 1
a.eat();
```

I know in this case method is getting overridden and run-time binding takes place. But what is the criteria using which compiler skips the compile time binding?

**My assumption**:Does it sees that data type and constructor calling are of different class (in line 1) and because of this difference it skips compile time binding?

3.In the code below:

```
 Animal a = new Horse();
 a.eat("some string");//compile time error
```

If my assumption is true, this code shouldn't result in compile time error, since compile time binding is already skipped. I can't understand why it is producing compile time error.
Can someone clarify?

Comment: There is no 'skipping of compile time binding'.

Comment: Compile time binding is not "skipped". When you call a virtual method, the compiler knows that there will be a method implementation in a particular slot that will be found at run time. It doesn't know that `a` will have an `eat(String)` method, because the type of `a` (`Animal`) doesn't specify such a method.

Comment: @Whatzs What about code 2 ?

Comment: It's not skipped, compiler just knows that it will be determined at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance method invocation rules are quite straightforward:

- The method *signature* is chosen at compile time.
- The specific *implementation* of the method with that signature is chosen at runtime. This stays true even if the method and/or the class is final because the class could be recompiled and a new override introduced. The calling class will not be affected by these changes.

Comment: Reference for both points is the JLS: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

Comment: (For static methods, both the signature and the implementation are chosen at compile time.)

Answer (score 2):

It's *almost* always runtime binding. I.e. all the java methods are virtual methods. Except static methods that are not virtual.

Final and private methods cannot be overridden either.

Still, we do have some compile-time type checks in java. In the following code you have a compile error because the class `Animal` has no `eat(String)` method.

```
Animal a = new Horse();
a.eat("some string");//compile time error
```

If `Animal` had an `eat(String)` method, then the code would compile. But, due to runtime binding, it would execute `Horse.eat()`.

In dynamically typed languages, like python or javascript, there is no such type check. If the method exists at runtime, it gets invoked. Otherwise an error is thrown. This is also called [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: Yeah, mentioning 'virtual methods' and 'dynamic dispatch' would be just enough. People who work with Java should know these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses the *actual class* to locate the required method at runtime, but it uses the *interface* to tell whether there *actually is* a method at compile time.  Your class **Animal** *implicitly* also defines an **Animal** interface, which in this case consists solely of the *no-argument* method 'eat()'.  It does NOT define a one-argument method 'eat(String)'.  Class **Horse** implicitly defines a **Horse** interface which extends the **Animal** interface with the one-argument method.

In your examples (1) and (2), regardless of which actual class you instantiate, you *assign* to a variable implementing the **Animal** interface.  Therefore when the compiler sees the statement 'a.eat();' it checks if the interface of 'a' implements a no-argument method 'eat()' - which it does.  In your example (3), the actual class is **Horse** BUT the variable still implements only the **Animal** interface; at statement 'a.eat("some string");' it checks if 'a' implements 'eat(String)' - which it doesn't, hence the compile-error.